# Pausing a script that has been piped to sh

Tags: bash, shell, curl, pipe

If i run

```
echo "read -p 'test'" | sh
```

Nothing happens. How can I get the effect I want?

Note: the reason I want to do this is because I keep a number of scripts like [this one](https://gist.github.com/drew-gross/5706361/raw/update_settings_and_dotfiles.sh) on github and I run them by doing

```
curl https://gist.github.com/drew-gross/5706361/raw/update_settings_and_dotfiles.sh | sh
```

Comment: when you run `echo something |sh`, stdin of the spawned sh is already redirected. & The `read` called by sh will also use the same redirected `stdin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipeing the script into a shell means that the shell is not interactive. Try sourcing it into the current shell:

```
. <(echo "read -p test")
. <(curl "$url")
```

Comment: This results in a syntax error:
`sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token '('`
`sh: line 3: '. <(read -p "Is iTerm2 running? You should quit it!")'`

Comment: Also, `. <(read -p foo)` will try to execute your *response* in the current shell. Treat a process substitution like a file filled with the output of the contained script. And in this case, you're trying to *source* the contents of the file, so it has to be valid shell commands.